# Destructured imports vs namespace in react libraries using typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, esmodules

My question is : is there any consequences in performance if using for  example:

```
import * as Reanimated from 'react-native-reanimated'
```

Instead of :

```
import { useSharedValue, useAnimatedStyle, withspring, interpolate, Extrapolate } from 'react-native-reanimated'
```

Will react load all the library when using namespace ?
Is there any différence when testing in thé two approaches ?

Comment: It doesn't matter enough to worry

Answer (score 1):

Import on-demand individual components or utils:

Here is the example of `antd`

**Example:**

```
import Button from 'antd/es/button'; 
import { Button } from 'antd'; // Imports all library
```

Here is another example of `lodash`. Only load required utils.

**Example:**

```
import assignIn from 'lodash/assignin';
import isPlainObject from 'lodash/isplainobject';
import isFunction from 'lodash/isfunction';
```